# How to implement camel kafka producer and consumer which is using kafka brokers and user name and password but not ssl certs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-producer-api, message-hub

How to implement camel kafka producer and consumer which is using kafka brokers and user name and password but not ssl certs.

my kafka broker configurations look like this

```
{
    "kafka_brokers_sasl":
    "kafka04-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka02-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka01-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka03-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093"
  ,
  "user": "**********",
  "password": "********"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to connect to Message Hub you need at least Apache Camel 2.20.

Then add the following query parameters to your URI:

- saslMechanism=PLAIN
- securityProtocol=SASL_SSL
- sslProtocol=TLSv1.2
- sslEnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
- saslJaasConfig=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD";

For example, for a producer:

```java
final String brokers = "kafka01-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093,kafka02-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093,kafka03-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093,kafka04-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093";

final String saslJaasConfig = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"USERNAME\" password=\"PASSWORD\";";

from("direct:in")
.to("kafka:test?" 
    + "brokers=" + brokers
    + "&saslMechanism=PLAIN"  
    + "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL"
    + "&sslProtocol=TLSv1.2"
    + "&sslEnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2" 
    + "&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS"
    + "&saslJaasConfig=" + saslJaasConfig);
```

and a consumer:

```java
final String brokers = "kafka01-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093,kafka02-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093,kafka03-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093,kafka04-orgName.services.orgsj001.us-west.bluemix.net:9093";

final String saslJaasConfig = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"USERNAME\" password=\"PASSWORD\";";

from("kafka:test?" 
    + "brokers=" + brokers
    + "&saslMechanism=PLAIN"  
    + "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL"
    + "&sslProtocol=TLSv1.2"
    + "&sslEnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2" 
    + "&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS"
    + "&saslJaasConfig=" + saslJaasConfig
    + "&groupId=mygroup")
.to("stream:out");
```

Comment: I am using 2.24.0 version of camel-spring-boot,camel-spring-boot-starter and camel-kafka in my dependecies with 2.1.2.RELEASE spring-boot-starter-parent. saslJaasconfig when used as what you have answered gives error
"failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password" and keeps trying on and on to connect.While the same sasl jaas config with 2.1 java kafka client works without any error. Can you tell which version of camel you used for your testing?